# How to store bitcoin and USD on the same django models field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

To store USD I am using DecimalField:

```
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
```

But what if I want to store bitcoins? Bitcoin's minimal thing is satoshi. One bitcoin = million satoshi. I have 2 options: using `DecimalField` with `decimal_places=5` or using an IntegerField. But I do not want to have a sepperate field for storing this. Is there any way to organize storing bitcoin and USD in the same field?

Comment: why not also store usd with 5 decimals?

Comment: Because USD's minimal thing is cent. You can not have 9.001$, but can have 9.99$.

Comment: yes but if you dont input 9.001$ to your field, then you won't have these "impossible" values inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store two different currencies in the field, you will have a second field that stores the currency, otherwise it is already wrong to begin with.

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

So simply use your currency field to differenciate between BTC and SAT(oshi).

Alternatively, you could *never* store a value in BTC and *always* store Satoshi. But then you would still need to be able to differenciate between USD and SAT.

Comment: In the models I have created custom clean method. I am using Decimal.quantize() to avoid too much numbers like 0.003$